# Slow fragment creation

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a view pager with multiple fragments but, I'm facing some performance problems as the onCreateView of the fragment is really slow. I've seen that the fragment takes some time to create the view, why is this?
In order to solve that I've thought about using a private variable so the view mustn't be recreated each time. The code would be as bellow (as you can see in the code, the content of the fragment is just a recyclerview):

```
private View iView; 

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(iView != null) {
        return iView;
    }
    iView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_view, container, false);

    rv = (RecyclerView) iView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final GridLayoutManager iLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), MAX_COLUMNS);
    rv.setLayoutManager(iLayoutManager);
    rv.setAdapter(iAdapter);
    rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    return iView; 
}
```

Is that a good solution? Why inflating the view may be taking so time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may be the content of those fragments that is making it slow, what did you implement in those fragments?

Comment: Hi, the fragment just contains a RecyclerView. I've edited the post in order to add the code I have in the onCreateView method

Comment: This code looks correct, the issue should be from your adapter

Comment: Is it correct to return the iView without inflating it (in case that it's not null) or it may lead to problems?